# Raspberry serial port automatically stops after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I am using neo 6m gps module with raspberry pi 3 , i have attached it on serial port ttyAMA0 , but it reads data for only small time and then port closes automatically , and sometime the data is also corrupt which causes gps.js module to throw an error.

[Execution Demo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhYiW.png).

Below is my node js script:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


var file = '/dev/ttyAMA0';

const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const parsers = SerialPort.parsers;

const parser = new parsers.Readline({
  delimiter: '\r\n'
});

const port = new SerialPort(file, {
  baudRate: 9600
});

port.pipe(parser);


var GPS = require('../../gps.js');
var gps = new GPS;

gps.on('GGA', function(data) {
  io.emit('position', data);
  console.log("Latitiude :", data.lat);
  console.log("Longitude :", data.lon);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/maps.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function() {

  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

port.on('data', function(data) {    
  gps.updatePartial(data);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', function (reason, p) {
  //I just caught an unhandled promise rejection, since we already have fallback handler for unhandled errors (see below), let throw and let him handle that
  console.log("=============");
  console.log(reason);
  console.log("=============");
  return;
});

process.on('rejectionHandled', () => {});

process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

port.on('close', function(data) {

  console.log("Port closed");
  console.log(port.binding);

    });
```

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhYiW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by reinstalling the raspbian, OS was closing the port for some reason